# Produce a PMML file for the Nnet model in python

Tags: python, neural-network, pmml

I have a model(Neural Network) in python which I want to convert into a PMML file . I have tried the following:

1.)py2pmml  -> Not able to find the source code for this
2.)in R     -> PMML in R works fine but my model is in Python.(Cant run the data in R to generate the same model in R) . Does not work for my dataset.
3.)  Now I am trying to use augustus to make the PMML file. But augustus has examples of using a already built PMML file but not how to make one

I am not able to find proper examples on how to use augustus in Python to customize the model.

Any suggestion will be good.

Thanks in advance.
GGR

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found my own solution. I wrote my own PMML Parser and scorer . PMML is very much same as XML so its easy to build and retrieve fields accordingly. If anyone needs more information please comment below.

Thanks ,
Raghu.

Comment: Hi Raghu... I too got one same requirement as your problem. I want to know the method you did in detail....